# the usage of "rest"

Tags: participles

I know *"It's impolite to sit down with your elbows **rested** on the table."* is correct, which just sounds pretty well to me, but I had also seen some sentence like *"AUDREY is sitting on the floor of her room with her back **resting** against her bed."* (Source:[Resting Sentence Examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/resting). I added *"with"* in the sentence myself.)

So if I use "resting", then the sentence becomes:

> It's impolite to sit down with your elbows **resting** on the table

But some how it is strange that both *"rested"* and *"resting"* are available in this sentence with the exact same meanings, so I am confused here.

**Cautions edited: the source provider of *"It's impolite to sit down with your elbows rested on the table."* told me that it is more appropriate to use "resting"**

So "rested" might be wrong now... but is it wrong?
(Consider it as "being" rested by me?)

Comment: I'm just curious: where did you find "It's impolite to sit down with your elbows rested on the table."?

Comment: @Damkerng T. In an exam paper, probably be made up by purpose.

Answer (score 2):

"Rested" is the simple past form and the past participle of the verb to rest. It would be used in sentences like:

> She **rested** her elbows on the table before speaking.

or

> **Rested** from her journey, she began again.

"Resting" is the present participle of the verb "to rest." It would be the most idiomatic form to use in your first example:

> Her elbows were **resting** on the table while she was speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in these both cases, when you use *resting* it's the process going on *(as it's specifically told that the **scene** is that, describing how the girl is **sitting**)*. On the other hand, when you are talking about the manners, you generally don't need the present continuous as that's not the **only time** when that manner tip is applied. So, let it better go with past participle making it the truth forever.

> It's impolite to sit down with your elbows **rested** on the table -*teaches the table-manners; 'resting' may work but then it may become a process of 'resting' your elbow there. Using 'rested' defines the posture of that manner.*

And,

> AUDREY is sitting on the floor of her room with her back resting against her bed - *is a 'scene' of something and needs to describe 'how is she sitting', it's more about her action of doing that'.*

Comment: "...with your elbows rested on the table" just sounds totally wrong. The idiomatic and correct way to say that is with "resting", ***not*** "rested". Unfortunately, this means I must downvote this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The verb *rest* is special in one respect: the meaning of the verb can change when you turn it into a past participle. Normally, a transitive verb gets a passive meaning when turned into a past participle, and an intransitive verb cannot be turned into a past particple; but *rested* can remain intransitive and not become passive as a past participle.

> I walked to Santiago.
>
> *Walked to Santiago, I was tired.

This is not possible with *walk* and most other verbs.

> My elbows rested on the table.
>
> Rested on the table, my elbows hurt.

*Agree* is another example:

> We agreed about the next step to take.
>
> We are agreed.